# Get address of ram sections during runtime

Tags: c, assembly, stack-overflow, ram

I want to implement a stack usage monitor for my NRF52840-Mikrocontroller with Segger Embedded Studio.

To monitor the maximum stack usage, I need some information during runtime like the end address of the .bss segment, which is the start of my free memory.

My approach is, to fill the ram from the .tbss section until to the stackpointer with a magic word.
During runtime, the stack will grow and will overwrite my magic words with data.
In a cyclic check, I am able to dedicate the end of the stack. From that information, I can derive the approximate stack usage.

Is it possible to get the addresses from the picture below during runtime in my c (or ASM) Program?

Here is a part of my .map file, where for example the symbol __bss_start is defined. Is it possible to access this symbol from c code?

```
 *(COMMON)
            0x0000000020020ec4                __bss_end__ = (__bss_start__ + SIZEOF (.bss))
            0x000000000001b8c8                __bss_size__ = SIZEOF (.bss)
            0x0000000020020ec4                __bss_load_end__ = __bss_end__
            0x0000000000000001                . = ASSERT (((__bss_start__ == __bss_end__) || ((__bss_end__ - __RAM_segment_start__) <= __RAM_segment_size__)), error: .bss is too large to fit in RAM memory segment)
            0x0000000020020ec4                __tbss_load_start__ = ALIGN (__bss_end__, 0x4)
```

[image: Ram Sections of the NRF52840]

Comment: Check your reference on this product. It's not something we can discern from a blurry screenshot.

Comment: What information do you need to discuss the problem? What is the problem with the screenshot?

Comment: In a similar situation the info I need was available via symbols made visible by the linker into compilers visibility. It was something like `_section_SECTIONNAME_start`. Would that help you (asking this to confirm my understanding of your question)? Can you find something like that in/for your environment. This is vague, becaue of my memory and becaue of the infos you provice. Hence only a comment. For an answer I could research the environment I refer to and the precise naming of the identifiers....

Comment: I understand implicitly that you do not use an OS, not even a tiny embedded OS like OSEK. But you might clarify this, becaue the presence of an OS (and which) would change the answer to your question significantly.

Comment: @Yunnosch: No, I am not using any OS, so I do only have one single stack in my whole application. I edited the question and added a part of my .map file. I don't know hot to get more information from my environment. I do not have access to a linker script. The memory placement is managed in a xml file, which is included by the Segger Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I have solved the Problem now.

To access the symbols of the .map file during runtime, I used the following code:

```
extern char __bss_end__;

int main()
{
    char * bss = &__bss_end__;
}
```

After this line of code, the bss variable contains the start address of the bss-section.
With this code, I am able to get the addresses of the RAM segments during runtime to monitor my stack usage.

Comment: Looks like what I meant. Assuming that I lead you to that discovery: My pleasure.